# how to join multi table mysql in vb.net and searching using TextChanged

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I have more than 4 tables and all tables have full name in column.
I want to search for name in all table and get the row of the name from all table.
I'm using TextChanged for search in table and the search for name is not working.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1

    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-C4O1PB3;Database=main_it;trusted_connection=true;")
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Dim sql As String

    Private Sub searchData(sql As String, dtg As DataGridView)
        Try
            con.Open()
            cmd = New SqlCommand()
            da = New SqlDataAdapter
            dt = New DataTable

            With cmd
                .Connection = con
                .CommandText = sql
            End With
            With da
                .SelectCommand = cmd
                .Fill(dt)
            End With
            dtg.DataSource = dt

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            con.Close()
            da.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  
        sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM igo UNION SELECT DISTINCT * FROM moe"


        searchData(sql, DataGridView1)

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged


        sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM igo UNION SELECT DISTINCT * FROM moe WHERE full_name LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%' OR mothername LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"

        searchData(sql, DataGridView1)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You use UNION - so all DISTINCTs are excess. WHERE in 2nd query affects 2nd subquery only.

Comment: Learn to use parameters!  Don't munge query strings with constant values.

Comment: `is not working` is not a valid error description for this site. Please describe your expected results, the actual results and the error message if any.

Comment: i have 4 table and each table have number of column
the name of table (igo,moe,theq,anbr)
each table have the same name of column
(full name , departmant , state , brath ,jobs)

i want to to search for "full name" in all 4 table 

i using vb.net and mysql i'm try to suing UNION  and it's not work